# Schema Registry for Protobuf Schemas

Tags: protocol-buffers

I'm conducting an investigation into the use of Protobuf for my organization and have a need to perform schema discovery. I've seen a number of articles related to Confluent Schema Registry with Avro. What are folks using for Protobuf?

Comment: So … Google has something internal for their own data platform. It is not applicable outside, nor is there an obvious solution bundled with the specs. I think the Protocol Buffers' 3 `any` has interesting applications to making a registry system.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is another SaaS solution being built for ProtoBuff Schema Registry called BSR, the Buff Schema Registry. It is currently in beta and they are welcoming the beta users.

Here are the details on this BSR: https://docs.buf.build/roadmap/

Click on the Join Waitlist for requesting beta user privilege here https://buf.build/

Comment: also [Apicurio Registry](https://www.apicur.io/registry/) supports protobuf

Answer (score 11):

**Update** : Confluent [now supports natively protobuf schemas](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/schema-registry/index.html#avro-json-and-protobuf-supported-formats-and-extensibility) in their schema registry, same as Avro or Json Schemas.

**OLD**: A majority of projects I've seen uses a git repository to store all their protocol buffer (.proto files). The goal is to share it with other teams. You can then import them as a [git submodule](https://blog.github.com/2016-02-01-working-with-submodules/) in any of your project

Comment: We went with source control for protos and a universal zip deployed as a consumable artifact.

Answer (score 7):

In the time since this question was asked 4+ years ago, Confluent has added support for protobuf and JSON schema [formats](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/schema-registry/serdes-develop/index.html) to its schema registry.

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for sharing Schema Registry, may I ask if you have an example about how to register a Protobuf file to Kafka Schema Registry with Schema Registry client? can't find any example

Comment: @Teng you can find info. about how their kafka protobuf serializer auto-registers schemas in the registry as well as the schema registry REST API and much more info. at https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/schema-registry/index.html .

Comment: thanks for your reply. I read the official doc, but not find any example in specific cases. Then I found ProtobufSchema class in Kafka Protobuf Provider, it can accept a String read from Protobuf file, and Kafka Schema Registry client can register this ProtobufSchema in Kafka Schema Rgistry

Comment: @Teng Here's an example of how to do it: https://gist.github.com/benissimo/d4fa3a9bd5561e14e96d029ffd6eee1d